# Syntax error: symbol "%" not allowed in string

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to create a progress bar which progress value is calculated with simple function in Angular controller file and afterwards it is sent to the html element into style attribute.

Here is the part of **AngularJS** file:

```
var statusMock = {
    installmentProgress: {
            current: '2',
            outOf: '4'
        }
}
var installmentProgressBarLength = ((statusMock.installmentProgress.current / statusMock.installmentProgress.outOf).toString() * 100);
ctrl.progressValue = 'progresValue={width:' + installmentProgressBarLength + '%}';
```

And here is the part of **HTML** file:

```
<div class="tile-policy-payments__installments-progress__progressbar" >
    <div class="tile-policy-payments__installments-progress__progressbar_value" ng-style="{{ctrl.progressValue}}"></div>
</div>
```

The problem is the "%" symbol in ctrl.progressValue definition. It causes the error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '}' not a primary expression at column 24 of the expression [progresValue={width:50%}] starting at [}].
```

If I don't use the "%" symbol everything works fine, however the length of progress bar is not the one that I expect.

[image]

Would be thankful for help in solving the problem. 
Regards

Comment: Not too familiar with `ng-style` but have you tried `ctrl.progressValue = 'width:' + installmentProgressBarLength + '%'` instead of `ctrl.progressValue = 'progresValue={width:' + installmentProgressBarLength + '%}'`

Comment: Yes, I've tried to write it this way too. Unfortunately, It did not work.

Comment: Ok just looked at the documentation, try  `ctrl.progressValue = { width: installmentProgressBarLength + '%' }`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change two things to get it working.
When setting the variable in JS, you should set it directly to an object:

```
ctrl.progressValue = { width: installmentProgressBarLength + '%' };
```

Second part is changing the binding:

```
ng-style="ctrl.progressValue"
```

Note that there's no curly brackets around the value. That's because what you actually want to pass to ng-style is an object and not a JSON representation of that object.